# Help me to get rid of unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

when I try to install it shows this. Help me to get rid of it. I tried to install codeblocks once with dpkg command.  **I am using ubuntu 20.04**

```
reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks-contrib : Depends: libboost-system1.62.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libhunspell-1.4-0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwxsmithlib0 (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is to be installed
                      Depends: codeblocks (= 20.03) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: valgrind but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cppcheck but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cscope but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cccc but it is not going to be installed
 codeblocks-dev : Depends: libcodeblocks0 (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is to be installed
 codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: The error message tells you what to do, twice. "`You might want to run apt --fix-broken install`". Do that.

Comment: But with sudo before that command

Comment: I tried, But it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do the following commands that might install the software and remove the error message

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt install codeblocks
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Firstly I would suggest trying the whole installation procedure using `aptitude`, since it provides solutions that most of the time work.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install aptitude
```

And then try downloading your package using `aptitude`:

```
sudo aptitude install <package-name>
```

**Step 2:**

If that doesn't work, try downloading the dependencies one by one to see if the problem goes away.

```
sudo apt install -f libcodeblocks0=20.03 # -f flag means fix broken
sudo apt install -f libwxgtk3.0-0v5=3.0.2+dfsg
sudo apt install -f libboost-system1.62.0
sudo apt install -f libhunspell-1.4-0
sudo apt install -f libwxsmithlib0=20.03
```

**Step 3:**

If the above steps don't cut it either (which I guess might happen since some packages are marked as `not installable`), try downloading those packages from *Ubuntu registry* for your computer architecture (I'll list for **amd64**)

**Links:**

[libwxgtk3.0-0v5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libwxgtk3.0-0v5/download)

[codeblocks](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/codeblocks/download)

[libcodeblocks0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libcodeblocks0/download)

[libhunspell-1.4-0](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/amd64/libhunspell-1.4-0/1.4.1-2build1) (right, under downloadable files)

[libwxsmithlib0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libwxsmithlib0/download)

[libboost-system1.62.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libboost-system1.62.0/download)

Hope this solves the problem. If not, comment below.